# Entity Framework and MVC 5. Data from database not shown on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I can't figure out what is problem. I created database with 2 table. On 1 table everything is shown on my localhost and I can edit/delete,save. Everything what I implement with CRUD. 
Can someone explain me what is wrong?

1.) Make model is shown properly, Model is empty

[image: Make is shown properly]

[image: Model is empty]

https://github.com/ivanradunkovic/Vozila/tree/master/Vozila

Here is link of GitHub, I will not spam here with long code.

`Models/Make.cs` and `Model.cs` (`MakeModel.cs`) is link between those 2. I don't konw if I need that
`DAL/VehicleContext.cs` and `VehicleInitializer.cs`

Please help me, I am crazy already :/

Comment: You will probably get much better feedback if you attach your debugger and see at which point do you get an empty model and then ask a specific question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a replacement for debugging. While we can certainly appreciate that you don't want to put *all of your code* in the question (since most of it is likely not relevant), simply linking to your project and asking us to go debug it for you isn't on-topic here either. Consider this an opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger. With one you can place a breakpoint in your code to pause run-time execution, allowing you to observe the runtime values of your variables and how they change from one line to the next. When you do this, where does the problem start?

Comment: Sorry I am new at programming so I ask for help when I stuck. This is my first C# project.

What I need to do? I put break point on "var models = new List<Model>" and all this code become red, I start debug and got this error. Did I debug wrong or? Please help me.
Debug output is too long to post

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the screenshot i attached [image: Error]. You are seeding the data with duplicate primary keys, thats why the data is not getting inserted in the database. Please change the seed values and make your Ids unique like this [image: Fix]

Comment: Thanks for your help but still the same. Anything other?

Comment: Delete the database and then run the app, according to your configuration it would seed data only first when the database is created. So there would be no changes at all if you just change in the code and run the app

Comment: Many thanks. I change Web.config database name and now everything is here. Many thanks for your help :)